# help with async_read_until

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I'm having trouble implmenting the 3rd parameter in the function documented here:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read_until/overload4.html
What I'd like to be able to do is use the callback on the 3rd parameter of async_read_until to detect when a complete chunk has arrived. My packets have the following format.

- 1 byte id  (semantic meaning of the data)
- unsigned int (the number of bytes in the data, since some data chunks can change size)
- payload

Looking at the example code in the documentation, I'm a little confused about how I'm supposed to be able to extract a byte, let alone an unsigned int from the begin and end iterators. 
I've instantiated my iterators as 
`typedef boost::asio::buffers_iterator<
    boost::asio::streambuf::const_buffers_type> iterator;`

but even then I'm not sure what type that is, since I don't know what const_buffers_type is. I followed some links in the documentation and found out it was "implementation defined", but I guess I could be wrong. 
So my two concrete questions are:

1. how can I use those two iterators to read an unsigned int?
2. what type are those iterators pointing to?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clearly state how do you define packet end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sample match function is presented in the documentation.

```
std::pair<iterator, bool>
match_whitespace(iterator begin, iterator end)
{
  iterator i = begin;
  while (i != end)
    if (std::isspace(*i++))
      return std::make_pair(i, true);
  return std::make_pair(i, false);
}
```

Dereferencing `i` here, pulls out one byte. You need to pull out enough bytes to match an int.

Remember however, that a callback is not the only option for read_until. Actually it's the most complex. Are you sure that it wouldn't be enough to use a regex instead?

```
template<
    typename AsyncReadStream,
    typename Allocator,
    typename ReadHandler>
void async_read_until(
    AsyncReadStream & s,
    boost::asio::basic_streambuf< Allocator > & b,
    const boost::regex & expr,
    ReadHandler handler);
```

Anyway, considering that your read is not delimeted, a lot better way would be to async_read_some until you've read the size, and then async_read_some with read at least.

Answer (score 1):

I have a very similar message format to yours (16 bit payload length, 8bit packet id/type, followed by the payload for me). I did it with a 3 phase read, and an array of function pointers for handling different things. I used boost::asio::async_read to read known amounts at a time.

This is a simplified version of my code:

```
//call this to start reading a packet/message
void startRead(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket &socket)
{
    boost::uint8_t *header = new boost::uint8_t[3];
    boost::asio::async_read(socket,boost::asio::buffer(header,3),
        boost::bind(&handleReadHeader,&socket,header, 
        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred,boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}
void handleReadHeader(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket *socket,
    boost::uint8_t *header, size_t len, const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    if(error)
    {
        delete[] header;
        handleReadError(error);
    }
    else
    {
        assert(len == 3);
        boost::uint16_t payLoadLen  = *((boost::uint16_t*)(header + 0));
        boost::uint8_t  type        = *((boost::uint8_t*) (header + 2));
        delete[] header;
        //dont bother calling asio again if there is no payload
        if(payLoadLen > 0)
        {
            boost::uint8_t *payLoad = new boost::uint8_t[payLoadLen];

            boost::asio::async_read(*socket,boost::asio::buffer(payLoad,payLoadLen),
                boost::bind(&handleReadBody,socket,
                type,payLoad,payLoadLen,
                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred,boost::asio::placeholders::error));
        }
        else handleReadBody(socket,type,0,0,0,boost::system::error_code());
    }
}
void handleReadBody(ip::tcp::socket *socket,
    boost::uint8_t type, boost::uint8_t *payLoad, boost::uint16_t len,
    size_t readLen, const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    if(error)
    {
        delete[] payLoad;
        handleReadError(error);
    }
    else
    {
        assert(len == readLen);
        //passes the packet to the appropriate function for the type
        //you could also use a switch statement or whatever
        //to get the next packet you must call StartRead again
        //personally I choose to do this from the actaul handler
        //themselves
        handlePacket(type,payLoad,len,error);
    }
}
```